# Dynamic Vue.js Steppy Component Steps Based on array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm currently working on a Vue.js project where I'm using the vue3-steppy component to handle a multi-step process. The steps need to be dynamically generated based on an API response. Each step represents a conflict type that needs resolution. The API response includes information about these conflicts, and I want to create a step for each conflict.

In my Vue.js component, I have implemented the vue3-steppy component to manage the steps. I'm fetching data from an API and using it to dynamically create steps in the vue3-steppy component. Each step corresponds to a conflict type that the user needs to address.

Here's a simplified snippet of my current setup:

```
<script setup>
// Imports and setup code...

const step = ref(1);
const conflictTabs = ref([]);

// Fetch API data and dynamically generate steps
async function fetchAndGenerateSteps() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5001/getConflicts");
    const data = await response.json();

    // Dynamically create steps based on conflict data
    conflictTabs.value = data.conflicts.map((conflict, index) => ({
      title: `Step ${index + 1}: ${conflict.type}`,
      iconSuccess: null,
      isValid: true,
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching conflicts:", error);
  }
}

// Call fetchAndGenerateSteps when component is mounted
onMounted(() => {
  fetchAndGenerateSteps();
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Steppy component with dynamically generated steps -->
    <Steppy
      :step="step"
      :tabs="conflictTabs"
      nextText="Next"
      doneText="Done"
      @finalize="handleFinalize"
    >
      <!-- Conflict resolution content for each step -->
      <template v-for="(conflict, index) in conflictTabs" :key="index" #1>
        <!-- Render content for each step based on conflict type -->
        <h2>{{ conflict.type }} Conflict</h2>
        <!-- ... Render resolution options for each conflict type ... -->
      </template>
    </Steppy>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
/* Styles... */
</style>
```

In this setup, I'm dynamically generating steps in the steppy component based on conflict data fetched from an API. Each step corresponds to a conflict type, and the user can resolve conflicts by interacting with the content for each step.

I'm facing an issue where the step number doesn't change dynamically with anything that i tried. I want the step number to change dynamically to reflect the current step the user is on (e.g., #2, #3, and so on).

How can I dynamically update the step number in the vue3-steppy component as the user progresses through the steps based on the API response? Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Steppy component found here:
https://github.com/Laximas/vue3-steppy

Answer (score 1):

Solved this Problem. The trick was to utilize dynamic slot names. You can find the details in the Vue.js documentation here:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#dynamic-slot-names

Example:

```
<template v-for="(conflict, index) in conflictTabs" :key="index" #[index+1]>
     <!-- Render content for each step based on conflict type -->
     <h2>{{ conflict.type }} Conflict</h2>
     <!-- ... Render resolution options for each conflict type ... -->. 
</template>
```

Using this dynamic Slot Name the name increases by one for every conflict `#[index+1]`